# Getting unexpected error when yml file is being parsed

Tags: snakeyaml

I have a bootstrap.yml file (for Spring boot) with the following section

```
producer:
  session:
    partition-submission:
      strategy: size-based
        size-limits: 10,100
```

I get this error when this file is parsed:

```
2023-03-31 19:16:02,280 ERROR [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed
org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 77, column 20:
            size-limits: 10,100
                       ^
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchValue(ScannerImpl.java:910)
```

If I remove the indent on the size-limits key then there is no error. If I put his in an online yaml linter it complains about the penultimate line and says:
`nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings.`

There are no tabs in the file, only spaces.
My main objective is to set and parse the 'size-limits' only when the 'strategy' is 'size-based', but not otherwise. How to get that?

Comment: remove the comma

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Removing the comma still produces complaints:
  
  Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings at line 4, column 17
  Implicit keys need to be on a single line at line 4, column 17

Answer (score 0):

Here, "strategy: size-based" forms a key-value pair.
It is not legal for a key-value pair to have indentation under it because that means the pair is mapping to a structure; only a key may map to structure as its value.

So the solution (albeit unsatisfying) for me is to change the YAML to

```
producer:
  session:
    partition-submission:
      strategy: size-based
      size-limits: 10,100
```

and just parse but ignore the size-limits if provided when the strategy is say "random" instead of "size-based".  Editors of the strategy may forget to remove 'size-limits' when strategy is changed from 'size-based' to 'random'.